# Consulta compleja de TEST DE GRAN EMPRESA

Tags: sql, sql-server, test

He hecho un test SQL de una gran empresa multinacional conocida por todos, esta pregunta me ha costado hacerla y no la he podido realizar.

Aqui os la dejo con un ejemplo de las tablas.

[image: Enunciado Pregunta]

[image: Ejemplo Tablas]

La idea es hacer tres counts cogiendo los dos primeros numeros de TRANSACTION_ID con LEFT no?
A ver si alguien es capaz de hacerla aunque no lo pueda comprobar!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo por tu pregunta que hay que obtener la cantidad de transacciones que hizo cada usuario en cada año (2019/20/21), ¿Verdad?

```
SELECT COUNT(t.transaction_id) AS Cantidad, u.user_Id As User, 
  CASE 
     WHEN transaction_id LIKE '19%' THEN '2019'
     --WHEN 2020
     --WHEN 2021
    ELSE 'otros'
  END AS 'Anio'
FROM transactions t LEFT JOIN users u ON t.user_id = u.user_id
```